# Should I sell or gift my vehicle (RV) to my own LLC?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, limited-liability-company

3 years ago I've purchased an old RV to use (and still using) it as a mobile office and laboratory. A month ago I registered an LLC and now I want to transfer the ownership of my RV to my company.

The question is: **should I sell it or just gift it?**

I understand that if I sell it, my LLC would have to pay sales tax, which is OK if down the road, owning a vehicle by LLC would give better tax advantages to the LLC. It's a 1994 RV that costs about $8,000 today.

Whether selling or gifting, the goal is utilize all vehicle expenses as 100% business expense. I'm using it only for the business and being electronic lab, there are a lot of equipment being installed for the businesses purposes.

I can even keep it in my own name rather than LLC's if I can still write off all business expenses associated with the vehicle, including gas and maintenance, just like FedEx or a transportation company would do; rather than just the per mile option by using personal car for business.

Comment: Obligatory Breaking Bad reference. :)

Comment: A comment because I do not know how to properly register it. It is not a gift, but an asset transfer. You can tranfer assets to your corporation, your vehicle will become part of the capital your corporation has. You can even deduct the depreciation of the vehicle (it depends on the rules of amortization, if a vehicle gets amortized in 10 years then 1/10 of its value) each year as an expense. The main rule is that the asset has to been used for your corporation activity (so you can not transfer the RV you use only for holidays and deduct its expenses), but you have it covered.

Comment: An LLC is not a corporation, so I removed the word "corporation" from your question.

Comment: https://www.score.org/blog/how-transfer-assets-your-llc ??

Comment: You might want to transfer the RV to the *Limited Liability* Company just for that: the limited liability: if you're tooling down the road heading to a job site and plow into a van full of children, that LLC won't shield you, because the RV is in your name.

Comment: Thanks SJuan76, I understand the benefits of deducting the depreciation. My question was about transferring the assets for money (i.e. selling) or without financial compensation, hence I called a "gift". In particular cons and pros of one versus the other.

Comment: Thanks RonJohn, I understand it exactly. However the original question remains unanswered.